# How can I show author column in Plone's folder_contents page(contents tab under one folder)?

Tags: plone

Plone version: 4.1.4
I have one folder containing 50 files. Author info can be shown through View--Display tab.
Now I hope to show author column in Plone's folder_contents page(Contents tab under the folder).  How could I get that?

Best regards.

Hugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder_contents view is not designed to be modifiable through the web (TTW).  However, you can modify it on the filesystem (the easiest way is probably to override it with z3c.jbot).

Alternatively, you can simply create a Collection, which can show different fields, and use that as the default view of your folder.

Comment: I'd hope to change the folder_contents view to select more contents uploaded by the same author.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [collective.listingviews](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.listingviews) which lets you make a new folder_listing view TTW.